# Getting original object of failed insert into GBQ in Google Dataflow

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Apache Beam for writing some objects into google Big Query. I use code like

```
pipeline.apply(...)
        .apply(BigQueryIO.<MyObject>write().withFormatFunction(...))
```

I found that I can use `.getFailedInsertsWithErr()` method to get what `TableRow`s were not inserted.

I'd like to get original `MyObject` objects which cause failed inserts to provide another way of its processing. Is it possible to reach this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible out of the box at the moment. After `BigQueryIO` [applies the format function](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a63d0b338c4b62896b1677d2ac81a09992d6cde3/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L1694) there is no reference to the original object left in the row.

Comment: Yes, I saw this. For now I've made joining initial PCollection with PCollection with failed inserts using own key to get initial objects. Haven't checked performance and even if it works but seems to be working solution.